# Point domain to Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

I'm currently hosting my domain at namecheap, unfortunately, I cannot add an A record when the nameservers are not pointing to the default ones.
Since my nameservers are pointing to my hosting it's impossible for me to change those.

But I still want to like my domain to my Tumblr blog.

Is this possible, so when I go to tumblr.domain.com, I want to see my Tumblr.
But I cannot add an A record, due to the things mentioned above.

Is it possible with a htaccess file? I don't want a redirect though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your domain is pointing to web hosting, then the A records are stored on your web host, not namecheap. You should contact your web host and ask them to create an A record for tumblr.domain.com that points to the tumblr IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a cname for yourPage.tumblr.com